# poetry woes - ModuleNotFoundError in visual studio code debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I've installed python10 on my windows machine.
I've installed poetry.
Both python and poetry run from the command line.

I clone a poetry enabled repository (this project works correctly on another machine).
I've updated the myproject.toml file to 3.10

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
defusedxml = "^0.7.1"
jsondiff = "^1.3.0"
pytz = "^2021.1"
```

run poetry update

I then run the project in the visual studio debugger.

and it fails with

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'pytz'
```

pytz appears in my poetry.lock

poetry show lists it

```
pytz                      2021.3   World timezone definitions, modern and historical
```

What am I missing?

Comment: HI, what is the content of `.vscode/launch.json` ?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to select a different Python interpreter first.  That is, you need to tell VS Code to use the Python interpreter inside the poetry virtual environment.  See if the following works:

#### Setup

1. Open up VS Code
2. Open up the terminal/PowerShell in VS Code ( keyboard shortcut: `` Ctrl + ` ``  )
3. Change your directory to be the folder where your project is ( ie, where the pyproject.toml and poetry.lock files are ).  This is normally done with a terminal/PowerShell command like `cd ./path/to/my_project_folder`

#### Changing interpreter

4. Open the command pallet ( keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl + Shift + P` or `F1` )
5. Search for "python: select interpreter" and select it with the mouse or navigate with the arrow keys and press `Enter`
6. Select "Enter interpreter path..."
7. Go back to the terminal/PowerShell ( keyboard shortcut: `` Ctrl + ` ``  )
8. Type `poetry env info --path` and press `Enter`.  ( Note: if nothing shows up, then you need to create a virtualenv by typing `poetry shell` into the terminal/PowerShell first.  Then repeat step 8. )
9. Copy and paste the result of step 8 into the prompt box at the top that says "Enter path to a Python interpreter" and press `Enter`

#### Extra: Using VS Code debugger inside of Poetry

If you'd like to use the VS Code debugger for this Poetry project, then continue to do the following:

10. Open up the .py file in your project that you want to debug
11. Set any break points by clicking to the left of the line numbers ( a red circle should appear for any break points you set )
12. Start the debugger ( keyboard shortcut: `F5` )
13. Step through the program ( keyboard shortcut: `F11` )
14. Enjoy! ^.^

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!! Not sure why this just got changed on me, but I needed to change my interpreter for poetry scripts to execute via the debugger.